# Share image with text on twitter?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

Code is working fine with text share only.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Ridiculously%20Responsive%20Social%20Sharing%20Buttons%20by%20%40dbox%20and%20%40joshuatuscan%3A%20http%3A%2F%2Fkurtnoble.com%2Flabs%2Frrssb%20%7C%20http%3A%2F%2Fkurtnoble.com%2Flabs%2Frrssb%2Fmedia%2Frrssb-preview.png" class="popup">Share on twitter</a>
```

But I want pass text with image is this possible with the same?

If any one have idea please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a twitter Summary Card for your website/page you want to share.

To create a Summary Card with large image: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image

Other summary cards with images: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary

So essentially (there are more details in the links) you have to keep Twitter meta tags (which you can find in the above links) in the head of your webpage, and when the person clicks 'Share On Twitter' it should just post your website link.

***ALSO***

The twitter cards are your safest bet. [Check this thread out, it may help you.](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-include-an-image-using-tweet-button-from-my-website/18149/12)